# How to test JavaFX with Cucumber?

Tags: testing, javafx, cucumber, bdd

I want to write a JavaFX Application using BDD and Cucumber.

I already found the TestFX library, that could help me here, but still didn't find a proper setup. My main problem is the restarting of the Application for the different scenarios.

I want to write a Background step like this:

```
Given that the application is freshly launched
```

This step can be implemented by

```
thread = new Thread(() -> Application.launch(appClass));
thread.start();
```

However the JavaFX lifecycle forbids the restart of the application. My next idea was to let the application alive, but to reset the scene of the application before each scenario. Here I am actually hanging. So far I did not find a way to get the started Application instance and to set a new Scene to its Stage. Any suggestions?

Or is there any easier way to do BDD with JavaFX?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/ocUbqljxAlI related?

Comment: By now, I moved to an alternative, not testing the gui itself, but the GuiModel. The architecture is kind of an extended MVC, where I have a model, a controller, a viewmodel(behind an interface) and the fxmlController. The controller listens to model and viewmodel and acts upon them. the viewmodel just models gui-related stuff and is the only class that knows the fxmlController. For testing purposes I replace the viewmodel with a dummyViewModel, send events from there and check its state.

Answer (score 0):

please check bellow web URL : (JavaFX with Cucumber)

```
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.cucumber/13614
```

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't find anything helpful there. Question remains... I also saw in the TestFX upcoming features note, that they want to integrate cucumber support later. I assume that presently there is no clean way to do it...